# Get CPU usage of operations on a table in a schema in HANA

Tags: hana

I want to track how much CPU is being utilized during the operations on tables in a given schema?
Is there any view or table that could help determine that? Or maybe even a view or query that snapshots the value would help.
I am aware of the view `M_HOST_RESOURCE_UTILIZATION` but this tracks the overall utilization of CPU and not just for a schema or a table.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such view on HANA and probably on any database. Because the overhead would be too much to track down CPU utilization on table levels.

One possible way is to make the below link:

CPU utilization <-> number of threads in state 'Running' <-> SQL statement in that thread <-> Table accessed by the SQL

Then you could find a very rough approximation of CPU utilization of tables.